# Asyncio Как правильно запускать и останавливать многопоточку

Tags: python, selenium, async-await

У меня есть код:

```
import asyncio
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
proxy_list = ["89.187.177.85:80","89.187.177.108:80","89.187.177.99:80"]

async def main(n):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server=http://{proxy_list[n]}")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    browser.get("https://web.telegram.org/#/login")

asyncio.gather(main[1], main[2], main[3])
```

Как правильно его запустить(например в 100 потоков) и остановить все, когда ктонить загрузился